# Acrobat Document level Javascript to set/clear multiple text fields

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a form with variously named text fields that can carry a value between 0 and 4.  Currently, I have a Document Level Script that will set the strokeColor if a value is present or not.  The trouble is, this conflicts with a script that sets the initial decoration of the text fields and causes all the fields to remove their decoration once you place a value in any one field.  How can I make this work and affect only one field at a time instead of all?  JavaScript isn't what I normally deal with, so this has been a lot of trial and error.

Additionally, there are a multitude of checkboxes with various names that have the fillColor and strokeColor removed when the "clear form" button is pressed.  How can I prevent this or set all the checkboxes back to their original, empty, bordered and background filled state?

I know the two scripts contradict one another, this is why I am asking for help.  I cannot figure out how to make this work, again, this is not my primary language I have experience with.

My function to clear the text fields, used with on Blur:

```
function clearReqADLDecoration() {
if (event.target.value == "") {
// Background light blue when blank
    event.target.required = true;
    event.target.fillColor = event.value ? color.transparent : ["RGB", 236/255 , 251/255 , 255/255,];
    event.target.strokeColor = event.value ? color.transparent : color.red;
} else {
// Background removed when text present
    event.target.required = false;
    event.target.fillColor = event.value ? color.transparent : color.transparent;
    event.target.strokeColor = event.value ? color.transparent : color.transparent;
}
}
```

My function to set the initial field background color, used as a custom calculation:

```
function setReqADLDecoration() {
if (event.target.value == "") {
// Background light blue when blank
    event.target.required = true;
    event.target.strokeColor = event.value ? color.transparent : color.transparent;
    event.target.fillColor = event.value ? color.transparent : ["RGB", 236/255 , 251/255 , 255/255,];
} else {
// Background removed when text present
    event.target.required = false;
    event.target.strokeColor = event.value ? color.transparent : color.transparent;
    event.target.fillColor = event.value ? color.transparent : color.transparent;
}
}
```

Comment: I may have overlooked it, but to which field's Blur event do you attach the script?

Comment: @MaxWyss I Am working on a solution I might have found.  I am pretty sure the error lies with me and the code I wrote.  I will be posting an edit to my original question shortly.  But to answer yours, I am attaching this code to every text field's Blur event.